# Scrapy crawl loop for next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

Hello I am trying to get into word scrapers and crawlers however I don't understand why my code is not going to the next page and looping.

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy import*

    import scrapy 
from scrapy import*

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.thehousedirectory.com/category/interior-designers-architects/london-interior-designers/']
            
     
    def parse(self, response):

        allbuyers = response.xpath('//div[@class="company-details"]')

        for buyers in allbuyers:

            name = buyers.xpath('.//div/a/h2/text()').extract_first()
            email = buyers.xpath('.//p/a[contains(text(),"@")]/text()').extract_first()
            
            yield{

                'Name' : name,
                'Email' : email,

            }  
        
        next_url = response.css('#main > div > nav > a.next.page-numbers')

        if next_url:
            print("test")
            url = response.xpath("href").extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did to get the next page doesn't really make any sense. To be specific, this line I meant `url = response.xpath("href").extract()`

Here is the modified version of your spider:

```
class HouseDirectorySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'thehousedirectory'
    start_urls = ['https://www.thehousedirectory.com/category/interior-designers-architects/london-interior-designers/']
            
    def parse(self, response):
        for buyers in response.xpath('//*[@class="company-details"]'):
            yield {
                'Name' : buyers.xpath('.//*[@class="heading"]/a/h2/text()').get(),
                'Email' : buyers.xpath('.//p/a[starts-with(@href,"mailto:")]/text()').get(),
            }  
        
        next_url = response.css('.custom-pagination > a.next:contains("Next Page")')
        if next_url:
            url = next_url.css("::attr(href)").get()
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 1):

So as per your code the `next_url` variable returns nothing so loop will break but what you can in this way

```
.
.
next_url = response.css("nav.custom-pagination > a.next::attr(href)").get()

if next_url:
    yield scrapy.Request(next_url, self.parse)
```

This code also works where scraper is not able to found `NEXT PAGE` DOM element.